# Surjective multiplicative functional from a Banach algebra to $\mathbb{C}$ has a closed kernel?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a unital Banach algebra and let $f : A \to \mathbb{C}$ be a multiplicative linear functional which is onto. How can I show that the kernel of $f$ is closed or equivalent: $f$ is continuous?

Comment: Do you know that if $a\in A$ and $\|a-1\|<1$ then $a$ is invertible?

Comment: Yes, thats a consequence of the Neumann series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M$ be the kernel of $f$.  Since $A/M\cong\mathbb{C}$ is a field, $M$ is a maximal ideal of $A$.  But $\overline{M}$ is an ideal containing $M$, so if $\overline{M}\neq M$ then $\overline{M}$ must be all of $A$.  However, any $a\in A$ such that $\|a-1\|<1$ is invertible, and in particular is not in $M$.  Thus $1\not\in\overline{M}$, so $\overline{M}\neq A$, so $\overline{M}=M$.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thanks for the answer. One additional question. If we assume that f maps into the Banach algebra $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ then the proof should be exactly the same right (just change $A/M\cong\mathbb{C}$ to $A/M\cong\mathbb{C^{n \times n}}$)

Comment: Yes, since $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is a simple algebra.